# Show all columns separate by specific column

Tags: php, mysql, categories

In mysql i have 4 columns for example:

Table name is 'categories'

```
 ______________________________
|id | name | lastname    | slug |
 _______________________________|
|1  | Adam | Walkers     | Test1|
|2  | Nick | Myerson     | Test2|
|3  | John | Nicolas     | Test1|
|_______________________________|
```

The output should be:

```
Test1
Adam Walkers
John Nicolas

Test2
Nick Myerson
```

Should i make something like this? `SELECT * FROM categories GROUP BY slug` and use foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there.

For an easy solution, if you're a beginner, I suggest you to use before it an ORDER BY statement

```
SELECT slug, name, lastname FROM categories ORDER BY slug
```

Result

```
Test1 | Adam | Walkers 
Test1 | John | Nicolas
Test2 | Nick | Myerson
```

and then group it by slug value with loops via code.

Example of implementation in php

```
$grouped_types = array();
$example_categories = [["Test1", "Adam", "Walkers"],["Test1", "John", "Nicolas"],["Test2", "Nick", "Myerson"]];
 
//SET categories grouped
foreach($example_categories as $value){
  $grouped_types[$value[0]][] = "{$value[1]} {$value[2]}";
}

//GET categories grouped
foreach(array_keys($grouped_types) as $slug){
    echo "<h1>{$slug}</h1>";
    foreach($grouped_types[$slug] as $names){
        echo "<p>{$names}</p>";
    }
}
```

Final result

```
Test1
Adam Walkers
John Nicolas

Test2
Nick Myerson
```

Alternative, use an GROUP_CONCAT statement as mentioned by [saurabh kackar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71970267/17606071) like this

```
SELECT slug, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(name, ' ', lastname)) as names
FROM categories
GROUP BY slug;
```

Result

```
Test1 | Adam Walkers,John Nicolas |
Test2 | Nick Myerson              |
```

Finaly, use an explode function to split the names

Good work!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to do in a single query then you may use **GROUP_CONCAT()** function in MySQL.